# PHP HTML email gets sent with tags

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

```
$to = 'jay@mywhitecard.ph';
$subject = 'Coupon Claimed!';
$header  = 'From: info@mywhitecard.ph';
$claimed = '<html><body>';
$claimed .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$claimed .= '</body></html>';


mail($to, $subject, $claimed, $header);
```

I have this simple html php email but when it is sent everything including tags gets included.

[image: 1]

googled tutorials show similar examples like the code i did, would like to know how I can only send the div content.

Comment: you need to set the headers content type to `text/html` like this `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`

Comment: thanks this made it work, but i had to remove the edited "From" email (like From: info@gmail.com) in order for this to work, how do I have them function at the same time?

Comment: add `$header .= 'From: <info@myshitecard.ph>' . "\r\n";` after your Content-Type header. -- you have to have both the content-type and the from. The `.=` means to "add this to the variable" (to concatenate the strings together). So both of those lines will be in the header.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak hahaha @ the code example `;-)`

Comment: Instead of sending e-mails directly via `mail()` you should consider to use a mailer class like [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Sending HTML emails with such classes is much simpler as implementing all required RFCs rules by self. Besides that you can also define a plain content without HTML because some users don't like to read HTML e-mails (like me) and show emails as PLAIN instead!.

Comment: @Martin I didn't see the typo and now I can't edit it lol

Comment: adding $header .= 'From: <info@mywhitecard.ph>' . "\r\n"; sends the content with tags

Comment: @JeffVdovjak ahhhh, what a world we live in! `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Content-type to your header like this:

```
$to = 'jay@mywhitecard.ph';
$subject = 'Coupon Claimed!';
$claimed = '<html><body>';
$claimed .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$claimed .= '</body></html>';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: info@mywhitecard.ph\r\n';

mail($to, $subject, $claimed, $headers);
```

Comment: maybe its only on my end but using this turns the content to tags again

Comment: I changed the last $headers line (it ends with `\r\n` now). Does that work?

Comment: still the same unfortunately

Comment: Is the "From" missing too? Because there's a typo on the code above (I will correct). In the mail() function it said $header and not $headers. (it should have thrown a notice -- but not an error).

Comment: ah how silly of me, was checking an alternative solution but the problem is just a typo. anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @ButtonPress Silly of me! I'm glad it's working for you. It's handy to have notices when you're debugging ;)